# Use Automator to perform a FFmpeg command (two .SRT in one .MP4)

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, automator

I have the script below which I'm used to running from Terminal and it works perfectly. I just need to have one single `.mp4` file and two `.srt` files in my user directory and it will automatically input both subtitles into a new `.mp4` file, while also changing the codec to HVC1.

But I'd like to simply select 3 files (two `.srt` and one `.mp4`) from Finder, get their file names, path, and extension, and run this as a service. How could I do that? I have checked tons of options on the internet but I don't know how to do it. Please, could somebody help me?

```bsh
ffmpeg -i movie-1.mp4 -i movie-2.srt -i movie-3.srt \
-map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 -map 2 \
-c:v copy  -tag:v hvc1 -c:a copy -c:s mov_text \
-metadata:s:s:0 language=por -metadata:s:s:1 language=eng \
/Users/allanmentzingen/Desktop/output.mp4
```

Comment: What have you already tried? You say you've checked “options on the internet”, but what are these? Have you started building a simple Automator task that uses one file, etc.?

Comment: I've tried using arguments in a shell script, also tried applescript with filesString and POSIX path of file... It seems I'm not writing the script as it should

Comment: Please edit your question and show what you have tried, what errors you are getting etc. That'd make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Put your command into a "Run Shell Script" action, select "Pass input: as arguments", then use those variable arguments in place of your fixed arguments:

[image: workflow screen shot]

The "`$1`" etc. bits are the arguments to the script, first, second, and third.

Of the Automator "document" types, I'd recommend that you use a Quick Action, a Folder Action, or an Application, in that order:

1. A Quick Action would require that you select the three files, right-click the group, then pick your Automator workflow from the Quick Actions flyout menu.
2. A Folder Action would have you bind the workflow to a particular folder that you'd drop these files into.
3. An Application would act as a droplet, an [applet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applet) that runs with the files you drag and drop onto it: drag the three files onto the app icon to run it with those files as input.

I don't see that this workflow is sensitive to file argument ordering. The order you select files in Finder will affect the order of the `-i` options to `ffmpeg`, but I don't think `ffmpeg` cares in this instance. The only bit I'm uncertain about is whether the "`.mp4`" on the output file name is sufficient to tell `ffmpeg` to write the output in MP4 format, rather than get it from the first `-i` argument. If so, then you'd just need to add `-f mp4` early in the command.

Comment: It is not working. It tells me:
A " '' " can't go after this identifier.

Comment: @user1041098: That sounds like an AppleScript error. Are you sure you selected a "Run Shell Script" action, not "Run AppleScript"? Maybe post your workflow somewhere. Alternately, strip it down to a simpler command and build back up from there. It works here.

Comment: In fact, it says that the ffmpeg command was not found

Comment: @user1041098: So [install ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-mac), then. If you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed, you can say `brew install ffmpeg` instead.

Comment: it is installed. I am using it in an Applescript as a quick action

Comment: Then it is perhaps not in the PATH of the process that launches the Automator workflow. Give the executable's full path, most likely `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`. If that's not it, say `which ffmpeg` in the Terminal to get it to tell you where the command is.